# Couldn't find Vehicle with 'id'=search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a search working for my application however it only works for the first page when I click next page I get the following error:

[image]

I've the following code in my vehicles controller:

```
 def search
  vehicles = Vehicle.fuzzy_search(params[:search_string])
  @vehicles = Kaminari.paginate_array(vehicles.order:make).page(params[:page]).per(3)
  if @vehicles.empty?
    flash.now[:alert] = "No records found - displaying all records ..."
    @vehicles = Vehicle.order(:make).page(params[:page]).per(3)
  end
  render :action => "index"
 end
```

I've got the following code in my vehicle.rb

```
def self.fuzzy_search(search_string)
    search_string = "%" + search_string + "%"
    self.where("make LIKE ?", search_string)
end
```

and my routes.rb has the following:

```
get 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
post 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
```

For some reason its trying to show a record which is called "search" rather then displaying the second page. I've spend hours trying to figure out why its doing this can someone please help!

Edit --
Full Trace 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `next` button (and an example of the html that is generated for it)?

Comment: Can you show us your full trace please?

Comment: I'm using the kaminari gem so I've on got `<%= paginate @vehicles %>` which does the pagination for me

Comment: @ConnorGurney Full trace added

Comment: Can you also send your logs? Looks like your params are screwed up.

Comment: @RyanClark Where about are the logs?

Comment: @MAhmed Thank you — glad to see your problems are solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Exact Problem:**

If you see your error, it is pointing to **`VehicleController#show`**

It is happening because `get 'vehicles/search'` is going to show action but not `search`

Show will be something like,

`get '/vehicles/:id', to: 'vehicles#show'`, so the search it is thiniking as Id and giving you error.

**Solution:**

Move
 `get 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'`
above `resources: vehicles`

**Your search route should be on the top of vehicles show route**

So, your routes should be something like,

**routes.rb excerpt:**

```
get 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
post 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
resources: vehicles
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe is on the next button, where you send the form where your Search also is, and the ID is sent as "search".

Would be amazing if you could edit with your search form and your next button html code.

(not enough rep to comment on you question, i will add this answer with an actual answer if i can provide you with one)

Answer (score 0):

Please added in routes.rb file

```
get 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
post 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
resources: vehicles
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `config/routes.rb` file:

Move following lines to bottom of the file.

```
get 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
post 'vehicles/search', to: 'vehicles#search'
```

Comment: They're already below everything else but above `match '*a', to: 'errors#routing', via: [:get, :post]`

Comment: Maybe change  `vehicles/search` to `/vehicles/search` in routes.

Comment: Just tried that. Still getting the same error when going on another page.

Comment: @MAhmed: this answer is wrong. these routes should be before `resources :vehicles`

Answer (score -1):

If you are searching for a single record use -

```
Vehicle.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

If you are trying to find multiple records use -

```
Vehicle.where(id: params[:id])
```

instead of -

```
Vehicle.find(params[:id])
```

This will return Nil if the id you are searching for is not present and will not throw - Record not found error

Comment: This will only mask the problem instead of fixing it.